# How developers can assign Unique Id for HTML Controls in Grid which can used by Automation Test tool like Code UI?

Tags: angularjs, coded-ui-tests, ngtable

I am using Angular JS - ng-table. Which generates grid structure with Sorting, filtering, pagination features.

We are using Coded UI automation tools which expects all HTML controls should be Unique.

**For Example :**

Lets have Grid Table consist of Employee records.

Automation Tester wrote a test cases  expecting the first 1-10 records are having unique Id (Emp1-to-Emp10) which is NOT going to be changed.

But when Tester sorting the Grid then whole structure of Grid is being changed. 
First 10 records will have - Emp11,Emp1,Emp4,Emp5,Emp37,Emp42,Emp67,Emp89,Emp12,Emp10.

when the Tester re test the test case it FAILs .

So, how to maintain the consistency for dynamic records unique ids with the combination of Angular JS + Coded UI?.

Thanks
Gokul

Comment: The code would help, but personally I'd give who ever wrote the test a dictionary so they could look up what the word unique means as I daresay making the code pass this test would break the app, or not test it in any useful way...

Answer (score 1):

I would say that what is happening is expected sorting behaviour..

Some ways that you could solve your problem.  From the tester's point of view:

- Tests should restore the page to the initial state before ending.  For example if the test sorts a table, it should 'un-sort' the table before it finishes.  This leaves the data in an expected state so that the test can be repeated
- Don't select things by id.  All the test frameworks I know of allow you to select things by css selectors, which can do much more powerful selections than by id.  E.g. you could look up a row by the employee Id and it would find it regardless of what order the table is in.

From the developer's point of view:

- I presume the rows are items in an array.  You can assign a unique id as a property to each item in the array and use it in the template markup.  The unique id would not be affected by any sorting.

Unless you are using a very unusual framework or constrained by strange rules, I would suggest that the automated tests are amended rather than the code.

Comment: 1 .Test case can not control sort, pagination features as it involves with functionalities.  2. what in future we wanted to change the css class name.? It will lead to rewrite the test case.

Comment: css selectors are much more powerful than simply selecting class names.  You can select elements according to their contents e.g. "select the row that has employee id Emp11"